# how do i setup client-side input validation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, input, ecmascript-6

This is just a basic crud system but it is used as a generic system for re using it for other pages.

This function is used to create the input fields with its corresponding attribute and
insert each input to each cell of the  table row. This function has two parameters

1. attribute_obj is an array which includes column_type, attributes and icons
2. currentRow is the selected table row

```
function buildRow(attribute_obj, currentRow) {
    attribute_obj.forEach(element => {
        for (const [input_element_key, input_element_value] of Object.entries(element)) {
            if(input_element_value.column_type!= "actions") {
                var buildFieldBox = document.createElement(input_element_value.column_type);
                for (const [input_attribute_key, input_attribute_value] of Object.entries(input_element_value.attributes)) {
                    buildFieldBox.setAttribute(input_attribute_key, input_attribute_value);
                }
            }

        switch (input_element_value.column_type) {
            case "select":
                for (var i = 0; i < input_element_value.option_value.length; i++) {
                    var option = document.createElement(input_element_value.column_option);
                    option.value = input_element_value.option_value[i].value;
                    option.text = input_element_value.option_value[i].text;
                    buildFieldBox.appendChild(option);
                }
                break;
            case "actions":
                var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
                for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(input_element_value.icons)) {
                     var buildActionBox = document.createElement("a");
                    for (const [attribute_key, attribute_value] of Object.entries(value.attributes)) {
                        buildActionBox.setAttribute(attribute_key, attribute_value);
                    }
                    if (input_element_value.icons) {
                        var buildIconBox = document.createElement("i");
                        buildIconBox.setAttribute("class", "material-icons");
                        var text_icon = document.createTextNode(value.icon)
                        buildIconBox.append(text_icon);
                        buildActionBox.appendChild(buildIconBox);
                    }
                    currentCell.appendChild(buildActionBox);
                 }
                    break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if(input_element_value.column_type!= "actions") {
            var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
            currentCell.appendChild(buildFieldBox);
        }
    }
    });
}
```

```
// Append table with add row form on add new button click
function addNewRow() {
    var myTableElements = document.getElementById("myTableElements");
    var currentIndex = myTableElements.rows.length;
    var currentRow = myTableElements.insertRow(-1);

    const attribute_obj = [
        {
            name: {
                column_type: "input",
                attributes: {
                    name: "name",
                    type: "text",
                    id: "name" + currentIndex,
                    class: "form-control",
                    validations: "required|minlength:3|maxlength:20|numeric",
                },
            },
        },
        {
            element: {
                column_type: "input",
                attributes: {
                    name: "elementname",
                    type: "text",
                    id: "elementname" + currentIndex,
                    class: "form-control",
                },
            },
        },
        {
            type: {
                column_type: "input",
                attributes: {
                    name: "typename",
                    type: "text",
                    id: "typename" + currentIndex,
                    class: "form-control",
                },
            },
        },
        {
            select_multiple: {
                column_type: "select",
                attributes: {
                    name: "select_name",
                    id: "select_name" + currentIndex,
                    class: "form-control",
                    "multiselect-select-all": "true",
                    "multiselect-search": "true",
                    multiple: "true",
                },
                column_option: "option",
                option_value: [
                    { value: "Volvo", text: "volvo" },
                    { value: "Saab", text: "saab" },
                    { value: "Mercades", text: "mercades" },
                    { value: "Audi", text: "audi" },
                ],
            },
        },
        {
            select: {
                column_type: "select",
                attributes: {
                    name: "select_name",
                    id: "select_name" + currentIndex,
                    class: "form-control",
                },
                column_option: "option",
                option_value: [
                    { value: "Volvo", text: "volvo" },
                    { value: "Saab", text: "saab" },
                    { value: "Mercades", text: "mercades" },
                    { value: "Audi", text: "audi" },
                ],
            },
        },
        {
            action: {
                column_type: "actions",
                icons: {
                    add: {
                        icon: "playlist_add",
                        attributes: {
                            id: "add",
                            title: "Add",
                            onclick: "addField();",
                            "data-toggle": "tooltip",
                            class: "add",
                        },
                    },
                    edit: {
                        icon: "edit",
                        attributes: {
                            id: "edit",
                            title: "Edit",
                            onclick: "editField();",
                            "data-toggle": "tooltip",
                            class: "edit",
                        },
                    },
                    delete: {
                        icon: "delete",
                        function: "deleteField();",
                        attributes: {
                            id: "delete",
                            title: "Delete",
                            onclick: "deleteField();",
                            "data-toggle": "tooltip",
                            class: "delete",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    ];
    buildRow(attribute_obj, currentRow);
}
```

how do i setup validation for fields in this manner?

Comment: You can create a separate function that validates the form contents. The function uses `querySelector` to find the fields and validate the contents. Another option would be to add a `change` eventListener to all your fields and validate right away when the input changes.

Comment: Can you help me with a sample code?

Comment: Just a short example: `myValue = document.querySelector("namefield").value` and then a function to check if it is valid `if(!myValue) { console.log("name was not filled") }`.

Comment: You already have validation in place: The first input field "name" will be checked for min/max length and also for type "numeric". You can do similar things for the other input and select elements (for select elements simply set the "required" attribute).